# iOS 16 : Call connection established but app not opening

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, callkit, flutter-webrtc

I have used [flutter_webrtc](https://github.com/flutter-webrtc/flutter-webrtc) for video/audio calls and [flutter_callkit_incoming: ^2.0.0+1](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_callkit_incoming) for call notification. But in this case only in iOS 16 version when I click on the receive button. The call connection establishes and the call was received but the app not opening.

SO, is there any other specific code I have to do for iOS 16? Please help me with this issue.

Thanks in advance.